# Â character displaying before every $ character in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My code is for getting amount in dollars($) using angularjs. But " Â " character displaying before every " $ " character in html. I need to remove that character. Thanks in Advance.

sample code:

```
<div class="control-label col-md-6">
    <strong>Amount Advanced</strong>
</div>
<div class="details">
    <div class="name">{{(loanDetails.loanProductStructure.remainingPrincipal
                                        || 0 )| currency }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ensure that your document's "charset" is set to utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue last week, so right of the bat, if you are using mssql try storing your data in an nvarchar column instead of varchar.

This has to do with character encoding. You can also try to set your doucument type in the meta to the character encoding of your preference `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">` or if it's utf 8 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` or even better have your webserver send the correct encoding type in the headers. If you can figure out in what character encoding your data is stored/sent

Character encoding is a bitch, and there are multiple solutions for it. You need to figure out what works for your data and storage type and output type.

Knowing which character encoding is in play is half the answer you need to solve your problem :-) The other half is using content type outputs or character encoding converters to convert it from one to the other, or changing the storage schema of your database engine.